# Insert statement not working when imputed by user

Tags: postgresql, python-2.7

Beginner here practicing and run into the problem below;

I want the user to input the name of the tool and whatever he typed to be passed to the sql database of the tools table. In the code below its only passing the name **InsertTool** into the tools table and not the actual value the user is writing. How do i make it so that whatever the user wrote is passed and insert into the database directly?

```
cursor = connection.cursor()
  InsertTool = raw_input("Please insert the tool that you want to add.\n")
  insert_tool = """insert into tools(tool_name, rental_days) values('InsertTool', '2')"""
```

thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

since `InsertTool` is a variable here, you can not use it directly into the query, what you can do otherwise is this:

```
cursor = connection.cursor()
  InsertTool = raw_input("Please insert the tool that you want to add.\n")
  insert_tool = """insert into tools(tool_name, rental_days) values("@InsertTool", '2')"""
```

What we are doing here is putting the value of variable InsertTool now, while you were putting the string "InsertTool" into the values, so it was getting passed just as it is.

Comment: Very nice, however whenever I try to run it I get ;  ProgrammingError('column "inserttool' does not exist\nLine 1: insert tools(tool_name, rental_days) values(@insertTool, '2')

Comment: You need to see the error, it says you tried `insert tools(tool_name, rental_days) values(@insertTool, '2')` while you should do this `insert into tools(tool_name, rental_days) values(@insertTool, '2')`. Tell me if it works. :)

Comment: Yup, so Im using the exact same code that you posted in your first answer and whenever I try to run it in my program it gives me the error ; ProgrammingError('column "inserttool' does not exist\nLine 1: insert tools(tool_name, rental_days) values(@insertTool, '2'). its strange because im not doing **insert tools**, im doing **insert into tools** .

Comment: Okay, seems like it is considering @InsertTool as a column name which is not present in the table. Can you please give `insert into [table_name]([column_1], [column_2]) values("@InsertTool", "2")` a shot?

Comment: yup that works, so now __@InsertTool__ is inside the **Tools** table , but whenever I remove the **" "** from __@InsertTools__ it gives me the error that I said before.

Comment: No, InsertTool is not in the table, but when we put the variable in "@__", it understood that it is some value for the first column. Thanks.